# Increase circle size depend on text inside SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to create circle SVG with text inside. 
I created following with text. But, when i text digit increase i want to scale svg circle.

I created following yet.

```html
<svg height=22 viewBox="0 0 18 18" width=22>
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" fill="#49f9b9" r="7" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    <text x="55%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.45em" font-size="11" fill={textcolor}>5</text>
  </svg>
```

But, now i want to create big circle if value increase. Suppose 10 or 100 or 5000 then i want to increase circle depend on it.

Something like below. I limited value till 4 decimal.

[image]

If I pass value in 4 digit then it goes outside circle.

```html
<svg height=22 viewBox="0 0 18 18" width=22>
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" fill="#49f9b9" r="7" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <text x="55%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.45em" font-size="11" fill="#252525">5000</text>
      </svg>
```

I tried to find way to scale circle but couldn't.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's clear then that it's not a *circle* what you need

Comment: Why do you use `svg` for this? would a simple `<div>` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use d3 lib :

```js
let fontSize = 32; //in px;
let txt = "9999+";

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", fontSize*2);

let text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 70)
    .attr("y", fontSize)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font", "300 "+fontSize+"px arial")
    .text(txt);

let bbox = text.node().getBBox();

let rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", bbox.x - fontSize/2)
    .attr("y", bbox.y)
    .attr("width", bbox.width + fontSize)
    .attr("height", bbox.height)
    .style("fill", "green")
    .style("fill-opacity", ".3")
    .style("stroke", "#222")
    .style("stroke-width", "3px")
    .style("rx", bbox.height/2);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

source : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929 (modified to fit your needs)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment @Thomas made. This seems easily accomplished with just a few lines of CSS.

```html
<div>
  <span id="text">9999+</span>
</div>
```

```css
#text {
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black; 
}
```

I didn't match any of the colors or give it a background color, but that's pretty straight forward from there. To me this seems a better option than an SVG and I hope it helps (unless your goal is to specifically utilize an SVG, then it won't).

Comment: As we increase the text it doesn't stay a circle, it becomes oval in shape.